# NPE in addTextChangedListener on a EditText in a Sherlock fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to add on `addtextchangedlistener` for an EDITTEXT which is available in my Fragment1.java which extends SherlockFragment.

I have pasted my Fragment1.java file and my Updated Log cat with errors on it.

Posted my full code

```
package org.kp.tp.reachout;

import org.kp.tp.general.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class ReachoutActivity extends SherlockFragment {
    private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
    EditText sendmail_subject, sendmail_message;
    Spinner spinner2;
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView spinner1;
    RadioButton doctors, specialization;


    public void enableSubmitIfReady(View v) {

        boolean sendmailSubject = sendmail_subject.getText().toString()
                .length() > 0;
        boolean sendmailMessage = sendmail_message.getText().toString()
                .length() > 0;

        doctors = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
        specialization = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioFemale); 


        if (sendmailSubject && sendmailMessage) {
            radioSexGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(doctors.isChecked()){
                spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if (specialization.isChecked()){
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        } else {
            radioSexGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reachout, container, false);

        sendmail_subject = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.sendmail_subject);
        sendmail_message = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.sendmail_message);
        spinner1 = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sendmail_tousers);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.sendmail_tohubs);
        Log.e("subject",sendmail_subject.getText().toString());

        sendmail_subject.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                enableSubmitIfReady(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                enableSubmitIfReady(v);
            }
        });

        sendmail_message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                enableSubmitIfReady(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                enableSubmitIfReady(v);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

And Log cat file.

```
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at org.kp.tp.reachout.ReachoutActivity.enableSubmitIfReady(ReachoutActivity.java:40)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at org.tpt.docglobal.reachout.ReachoutActivity$2.onTextChanged(ReachoutActivity.java:107)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7377)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9076)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:223)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5464)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5283)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2623)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7343)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:353)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1933)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1408)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2384)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:121)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3774)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3666)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:1982)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1698)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1689)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1959)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
08-31 06:32:21.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3277):     at android.os
08-31 06:32:25.274: I/Process(3277): Sending signal. PID: 3277 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post compete logcat here?

Comment: you must always paste logcat, it helps in tracing the problem.

Comment: have you correctly referenced your EditText ?

Comment: @twntee i have referenced text correctly.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia i have updated my post with my log cat.

Comment: what  enableSubmitIfReady(); method do? can you paste it?

Comment: so it is crashing due to the method call !

Comment: @BirajZalavadia i have updated my post with enableSubmitIfReady function code.?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia i want to enable radio group button if edittext field is not empty. Thats what i am trying.

Comment: sendmail_subject,sendmail_message had you findViewById() for these one

Comment: @BirajZalavadia i tried setting some text value and able to retrive using findViewById() function.

Comment: post your full log cat, by that we mean at least 20 lines from the error point !

Comment: @twntee see my updated posted. I posted my full code and my log cat file.

Comment: i think we have some problem with this line 
`specialization = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);` might be incorrect reference

Comment: @twntee thanks you are right. I missed radiogroup declaration part. Now its working perfectly. thanks for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we have some problem with this line

```
specialization = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
```

might be incorrect reference.